# What's up with MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet

For the longest time, I've stayed away from FETs and MOSFETs (when it comes to using discrete transistors in my circuits, that is).  I'm taking a current hobby project as an excuse to try and finally get comfortable with using them. However, I can't seem to make heads or tails from these beasts.

Before trying any real circuits, I'm running basic (almost "sanity check") LTspice simulations.  Extremely simple circuits, and they still don't seem to work.  For example, see this LTspice screen capture below — the voltage probe is at the output of the power supply; the current is measured through the resistor connected to the Drain pin.  It is supposed to be 1mA when the MOSFET conducts (V2 is 12Volts), and I expect it to go back to 0mA for 1μs when the input voltage is 0V:

[image]

BTW, if I make V1 a DC source, then it works: I set it to 0V and the current through R1 is 0mA (well, in the order of pA), and if I set it to 5V, current is 1mA.

What am I missing? I also tried with a 100Ω resistor from V1 to the gate; it just makes a little round-ish bump in the current when switching, but it still does not come back to 0mA. I also added a 10k resistor from gate to GND. See image below, showing the output of the simulation (and again: what am I missing?):

[image]

I do have some more concrete questions on the topic, but I figure I better get comfortable with the simplest "toy" circuits before I try to do any "real" applications (even in the context of hobby projects).

Comment: Looks like you're switching your FET too quickly - try the first one again, this time with the gate voltage changing every second or so.

Comment: Try a fast switching transistor like the 2N700x.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do the same simulation on a **vastlty** different time scale, like 1000 times slower. So change the us (micro seconds) to ms (milli seconds) and run the simulation again.

Note how in the first plot the red trace is going down but before it reaches zero you switch the NMOS on again. It has no time to reach zero !

There is a large capacitor present between gate and drain and combined with the 12 k drain resistor that is a large time constant. Larger than the 1us you're allowing it. So slow things down and see what happens.

When you get the curve you expect, lower the value of the drain resistor and note how the speed increases again. At 1 us you probably need 120 ohms or so, not 12 k ohm).

Comment: Ah. An answer beat my comment. Yes, gate capacitance will be the cause for the slow switching off of the FET.

Comment: According to the manual of this part (fast switching N channel), worst turn-on/turn-off case is 42ns. Does that not take the internal capacitance in account? If not, where can you find the timing characteristics of the part? At 12V, the capacitance is roughly 1nF according to a table in the manual.

Comment: Aaahh — gate to drain capacitance!!  In my mind, there was this "input capacitance" that I see in the specs, and I was picturing this one as gate to drain capacitance affecting only the input signal.  It didn't occur to me to picture an "output capacitance" (so to speak).  At any rate (no pun intended), it is working now!  With the output resistor at 10Ω, it takes approx. 10ns for the output to swing.

Comment: As a meta-comment (if you indulge me) — funny how I seem to be very consistent with the mistakes/oversights/etc. I make ....  Not long ago, I posted here a question on (somewhat)high frequency op-amps, and guess what:  I was using my "default" resistor values (10k) that I'm used to for audio circuits, when in fact, for the bandwidth I was looking for, I needed resistors around 300Ω !!!  Oh well, I'll choose to see consistency as a good thing  :-)

Comment: I would also suggest looking closely at the turn on (at the gate) for the slower speed and seeing the gate plateau as the channel is pulled in. This is an inherent issue in enhancement mode MOSFETs, of course, but needs to be understood to get the most out of them.

Comment: @Lundin *worst turn-on/turn-off case is 42ns. Does that not take the internal capacitance in account?* Yes it does, **if** you could charge/discharge the gate **instantaneously** then the on/off time would be almost zero (time to make/remove a channel under the gate). That 42 ns is mainly caused by internal gate resistance so the gate cannot be charged/discharged instantaneously. Also there is often an external gate resistance specified which in combination with Cgs and Cgd determines the real fastest on/off time.

Comment: @Lundin The switching time is also highly load dependent. If you look at the operating condition for the turn on/off time, it will almost always be a "clamped inductive load". This load basically provides a constant current source at maybe 80% of the maximum drain current for charging the output capacitance.

Comment: Be sure you are comfortable thinking about Miller Effect. That has bitten me on both bipolars and FETS; that Miller Multiplication creates a huge input-energy-thief, and delays switching unless the Rsource is very low resistance.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf -- do you mean "Miller capacitance" (capacitance between drain and gate) leading to the need to "over-drive" the gate?   Miller effect refers to the "amplification" of the feedback capacitance by a factor (1+A), where A is the gain in a linear/analog circuit;  I'm not sure whether I'm missing something, as I don't really see how this applies to a highly non-linear (a sharp comparator) circuit like the MOSFET switching circuit in my post.  If I am missing something, please elaborate.

Comment: *I don't really see how this applies* Well it does, **during the transition** between on and off both gate and drain voltage change just like in a linear amplifier. The fact that the behavior isn't that linear or that it is only for a very short time does not matter. In that short transition time the effect is still there. If somehow the gate-drain capacitance could be eliminated then the switching would be faster under the same circumstances.

Comment: A "Miller capacitance" causes the "Miller effect" making the capacitance (as seen from the gate) look larger, you could call that "Miller multiplication" as the cap's value is multiplied by the gain. All terms describe basically the same effect.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie --- but doesn't the specified capacitance between drain and gate already account for the multiplicative effect? (i.e., isn't the specified capacitance the *effective* capacitance as seen from the gate?)  If not, I guess I'm having trouble seeing how we could determine the multiplicative factor.  Can you clarify? (or point me to some reading to help me clarify the subject)

Comment: The capacitance by itself: no, it is the combination with the gain dVdrain/dVgate that results in multiplication. If you would fix the voltage at the drain (using a voltage source) then there would be no signal amplification and also no Miller effect. As seen from the gate the capacitor would have it's actual value, not a multiplied value. The multiplicative factor is simply the signal gain. If the gate voltage changes 1 mV and the drain voltage changes 10 mV as a result of that then the gain is 10. A 1 pF capacitor would then appear to be 10 pF when seen from the gate side.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie -- Ok, I think I get it.  However, I'm not sure how do I deal with it.  If I can't determine dVd/dVg around the Vgs threshold, then I can't determine the effective capacitance during the switching.  Or I guess my question should be:  how do I determine dVd/dVg, or perhaps rather dRds/dVg around the Vgs threshold?  I guess if I'm running a SPICE simulation, all I need is be aware of this effect so that I over-drive the gate;  the simulation will take care of the fine details.  Right?

Comment: *how do I determine dVd/dVg...* When using a MOSFET as a switch, you generally would not calculate that by hand. The gain varies a lot during switching so it would be a complex calculation. Too complex to get a reliable answer in my opinion. Indeed using a simulator is a much better option and then it is easy to add all other components (gate resistor, load impedance) around the MOSFET as well making the simulation more reliable.